# how to call conditional useQuery hook in react/apollo

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, react-apollo, apollo-client

So I know I can use `skip` on query to skip them, but, this require me to do something like this

```
const [fetchQuery1, { loading1, data1 }] = useQuery({
 //..
 skip: cond1
});
const [fetchQuery2, { loading2, data2 }] = useQuery({
 //..
 skip: cond2
});
const [fetchQuery3, { loading3, data3 }] = useQuery({
 //..
 skip: cond3
});
```

but this is a lot of variable for some unused query

I have a code, where basiaclly there is 3 query, and only one will fire out of the three. Instead of creating a milions variable than add a `if(loading1 || loading2 || loading3)` I would like to have a single loading variable.

so right now I was doing

```
  const { data, loading, error } = cond1
    ? useQuery(Query1)
    : cond2 ? useQuery(Query2) : useQuery(Query3)
```

so the above works, but it goes against the rule of conditional hooks.

So I wonder if there is a nice way to do this, without polluting the variables

Answer (score 0):

You could conditionally pass the gql document to the useQuery hook.

```
const QUERY = cond1 ? QUERY1 : cond2 ? QUERY2 : QUERY3;
const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(QUERY);
```

Comment: hi, thanks, that would indeed work. But my mistake, I am also using the typings like 

`useQuery<T,D>()` so I guess I should use multiple typing there.

Comment: Yes, you could use unions to type the hook, but it won't as safe as just having just a single hook and single typing.